# em C. Passei um vetor para uma função e alterei ele lá dentro. Por que não alterou meu vetor na função principal? porque eu passei um ponteiro

Tags: c, funções, ponteiro, malloc

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void matriz_transposta( int l, int c, int *matriz);

int main (void){
    
    int linha = 2, coluna = 2;
    int *mat = (int*) malloc(linha*coluna*sizeof(int));

    mat[0] = 1; 
    mat[1] = 2;
    mat[2] = 3;
    mat[3] = 4;
    
    puts("Matriz original");
    int i, j, k;
        for ( i = 0; i < linha; i++)
            for(j = 0; j < coluna; j++){
                k = i * linha+j;
            printf("%d ", mat[k]);
            }
    matriz_transposta(linha, coluna, mat);
        
        puts("\n");
        puts("Matriz transposta");

        for ( i = 0; i < linha; i++)
            for(j = 0; j < coluna; j++){
                k = i * linha+j;
            printf("%d ", mat[k]);
            }               
}

void matriz_transposta( int l, int c, int *matriz){
    
    int i, j, k;
    int *ptraux = (int *) malloc(l*c*sizeof(int));
    puts("\n"); 
    for (i = 0; i < l; i ++)
        for ( j = 0; j < c; j++){
        ptraux[i*l+j] = matriz[j*l+i];
        printf("%d ", ptraux[i*l+j]);
    }
    matriz = ptraux;
    puts("\n");
    for ( i = 0; i < l; i++)
            for(j = 0; j < c; j++){
                k = i * l+j;
            printf(" %d ", matriz[k]);
            }
    free(ptraux);
    
    
}
```

Comment: Quando você faz `matriz = ptraux`, você está apenas alterando o valor local do ponteiro dentro da função. Você precisa ou modificar a própria matriz original dentro da função, ou copiar todo o conteúdo da auxiliar para a original (por exemplo, com `memcpy(matriz, ptraux, sizeof(int) * l * c)`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não alterou porque ***`int* matriz`*** é uma cópia do ponteiro.
O ponteiro aponta para a mesma região, mas não é o mesmo ponteiro.
Isso explica o porque de: *`matriz = ptraux`* só funcionar dentro do escopo da função

Em C, não existe passagem por referência, você sempre estará passando por valor.